# How to put Json array into Json object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm working with .Net Core 5.0 and creating Apis. On my following code

```
    [HttpGet("/User")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TokenAuth2Model>>> GettokenAuths()
    {
        return await _context.tokenAuths.ToListAsync();
    }
```

it returns data like below

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "username": "string",
    "userFullName": "string"
  }
]
```

but I want to get like below

```
{
   "users: 
    [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "username": "string",
        "userFullName": "string"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can try `return new { users = await ... }`. However, since you're specifying the exact type to return via the task you will need to create a named type with the Users property.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I cannot figure out this. It throws the casting exception .

Comment: Create a class: `public class Root { public IEnumerable<TokenAuth2Model> Users { get; set; } }`, then return this instead. You have to change both the type in the task in the return value, as well as the code that builds the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
 return new JsonResult(new { users = await _context.tokenAuths.ToListAsync() } );
```